# Why Log.v is not generating the output in Logcat?

Tags: android

Why Log.v is not generating the output in Logcat ?
I am new on Android. My app has four activities. Here I am pasting the code of NumbersActivity where I used the Log.v to generate output in Logcat.
Here is my code:

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
    String[] words=new String[10];
    words[0]="One";
    words[1]="Two";
    words[2]="Three";
    words[3]="Four";
    words[4]="Five";
    words[5]="Six";
    words[6]="Seven";
    words[7]="Eight";
    words[8]="Nine";
    words[9]="Ten";
    Log.v("NumbersActivity", "Word at index 0 is: " +words[0]);
    Log.v("NumbersActivity", "Word at index 1 is: " +words[1]);
 }
}
```

And this is the Output Generated in Logcat:

```
    04-26 01:12:15.229 24976-24976/? I/art: Not late-enabling -
Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-26 01:12:15.231 24976-24976/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 
using defaults: x86
04-26 01:12:16.083 24976-24976/com.example.android.miwok W/System: 
ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
/data/app/com.example.android.miwok-1/lib/x86
04-26 01:12:16.356 24976-24976/com.example.android.miwok I/InstantRun: 
starting instant run server: is main process
04-26 01:12:16.510 24976-24976/com.example.android.miwok W/art: Before 
Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter 
android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.
updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, 
android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) 
would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in 
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-26 01:12:17.163 24976-25009/com.example.android.miwok 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-26 01:12:17.163 24976-25009/com.example.android.miwok 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-26 01:12:17.164 24976-25009/com.example.android.miwok 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with 
EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-26 01:12:17.164 24976-25009/com.example.android.miwok 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
04-26 01:12:17.261 24976-24976/com.example.android.miwok W/art: Before 
Android 4.1, method int 
android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.
lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly 
overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
 Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
 implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
   -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.android.miwok">

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
   />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".FamilyActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_family"/>
    <activity android:name=".NumbersActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_numbers"/>
    <activity android:name=".ColorsActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_colors"/>
    <activity android:name=".PhrasesActivity"
        android:label="@string/category_phrases"></activity>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

Comment: You Logcat may be set to error or something else.

Comment: No. It is set to verbose. @resw67

Comment: Are you using any filters or, perhaps, a different selected package?

Comment: No. @Fondesa. ...

Comment: Using a line breakpoint on those two log lines, does the debugger stop?

Comment: file is not running in debug mode when i uses the line breakpoint, it says "Error running NumbersActivity: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filte"@Fondesa

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I had attached it in the question @Fondesa

Answer (score 0):

By default, `VERBOSE` is not logged.

> [android.util.Log#isLoggable(String tag, int level)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#isLoggable(java.lang.String,%20int))
>
> Checks to see whether or not a log for the specified tag is loggable at the specified level. The default level of any tag is set to INFO. This means that any level above and including INFO will be logged. Before you make any calls to a logging method you should check to see if your tag should be logged. You can change the default level by setting a system property: 'setprop log.tag.<YOUR_LOG_TAG> <LEVEL>' Where level is either VERBOSE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, ASSERT, or SUPPRESS. SUPPRESS will turn off all logging for your tag. You can also create a local.prop file that with the following in it: 'log.tag.<YOUR_LOG_TAG>=<LEVEL>' and place that in /data/local.prop.

In addition to using `setprop` (which has effect on new processes until the device reboots) and `local.prop` (which is read at boot), you can also use `System.setProperty` (for just your process).